# How to handle code nuggets when scripts are moved to a separate file from .aspx page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

In my aspx file, I have a script tag and some javascript codes. Since this being asp.net, to get an ID of an element, I have to use code nuggets like below:

```
function getName() {
  var a = $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val();
  alert(a);
}
```

If I want to move my script to a separate file and add a reference to that file in the .aspx page, how could the use of code nuggets be replaced in that file. It needs to be replaced some other way, isn't it?

Comment: Do you really have to give each hidden input an id unique to that user, instead of a general one, i.e., `#clientId`?

Comment: @royhowie: I am not sure what you mean there. I do not have any hidden input, it is just a regular asp:textBox, but since the id initially given would be changed to something else by asp.net, don't I need to use the ClientID property to get it? The issue is that these code nuggets will work on .aspx page's script tag, but what if I want to move all my scripts to a separate file?

Comment: Add a hidden input to the page with id `#clientId` and value whatever you want. Now, you can just have `var a = $("#clientId").val()` in your JS file, since the value was embedded into the html.

Comment: @royhowie: By any chance do you know of an example that I could refer to?

Comment: I don't know asp. However, it seems to use a similar syntax—`<%= %>`— to other embedding tools. In your html file, you'd add `<input type="hidden" name="clientId" id="clientId" value="<%= clientIdValueVariableOrSomething%>">`.